# The compiler I used is gcc5.1 but it seems that he did't support c++11

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "hello";
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    for (auto c : s1)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

I think the code is right, but it had lots of error message(please ignore the name of the code):

```
D:\>gcc hello.cpp -o hello

hello.cpp: In function 'int main()':

hello.cpp:8:12: error: 'c' does not name a type
  for (auto c : s1)
            ^

hello.cpp:11:2: error: expected ';' before 'return'
  return 0;
  ^

hello.cpp:11:2: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'

hello.cpp:11:2: error: expected ';' before 'return'

hello.cpp:11:2: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'

hello.cpp:11:2: error: expected ')' before 'return'
```

The book that i used to learn c++ is c++ primer, and I have learned c language before, but i still am a freshmen.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to that the flag `-std=c++11` (C++11) or `-std=c++1y`(C++14) to your compile command.